# Accessing history list GNU Readline

Tags: c++, shell, gnu, history, readline

I am in the process of making a shell in C++. I am using the Readline GNU with the history feature; trying to print out the history list with:

```
using_history();
int length = history_length;
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  history_set_pos(0);
  cout << HIST_ENTRY *current_history();
  cout << "\n";
  HIST_ENTRY *history_next();
}
```

When running this in the shell, it prints the addresses of the history entries in hex. How can I dereference so I can access the actual line that was called. I know that history feature for GNU uses the struct:

```
typedef struct _hist_entry {
char *line;
char *timestamp;
histdata_t data;
} HIST_ENTRY;
```

And the documentation for current_history:

```
HIST_ENTRY * current_history (void)
Return the history entry at the current position, as determined by where_history(). If there is no entry there, return a NULL pointer.
```

Comment: How are you printing the history?  It would be easiest if you showed your code, but it seems likely you are printing the pointer to the history text and not dereferencing it.

Comment: This is the only code I have for printing my history. Readline does a lot of the heavy lifting for history.